# overwrite a plugin function in functions.php

Tags: plugins, functions, pluggable

need to customise a plugin function but would rather not edit the plugin itself so updates wont remove the custom changes.

function iss in a class called *UserAccessManager* and the function is;

```
public function showGroupMembership($link, $postId)
{
    $uamAccessHandler = &$this->getAccessHandler();
    $groups = $uamAccessHandler->getUserGroupsForObject('post', $postId);

    if (count($groups) > 0) {
        $link .= ' | '.TXT_UAM_ASSIGNED_GROUPS.': ';

        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $link .= $group->getGroupName().', ';
        }

        $link = rtrim($link, ', ');
    }

    return $link;
}
```

is this possible? OR can i affect it with a filter?

Any help appreciated! Dc.

Comment: Exactly what you want to edit in this code?

Comment: wanted it to stop adding the text to my edit the post output which it laches onto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot alter the output of this function unless you directly modify the plugin code. The plugin author hasn't given you any filter to use.

So what can you do about it?

1. Continue to alter the plugin file and update each time the plugin updates.
2. Ask the plugin author nicely to add a filter to this function.
3. Make a fork of the plugin.

Comment: ah - ok well thanks for your input. Will make a fork of it...